# How to convert javascript array into geojson data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, leaflet

I want to upload txt, xls and csv files into leaflet. Firstly I am trying it for txt files. Js reads my txt as a js array. Now that I want to convert my js array into geojson. But I confused here. Need some clue about how kind a way should I follow. I appreciate your time and thank you for your kind replies.

```js
 $(function () {
            document.getElementById('file').onchange = function () {
    debugger;
                var file = this.files[0];
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (progressEvent) {
                    // Entire file
                    console.log(this.result);
                    // By lines
                    var lines = this.result.split('\n');
                    var list = [];
                    for (var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++) {
                        list.push(lines[line]);
                    }
                };
                reader.readAsText(file);
            };
        });
```

Comment: the data contained in your file would be useful.

Comment: name: 'Location A', category: 'Store', street: 'Market', lat: 39.984, lng: -75.343
 name: 'Location B', category: 'House', street: 'Broad', lat: 39.284, lng: -75.833
 name: 'Location C', category: 'Office', street: 'South', lat: 39.123, lng: -74.534

Comment: This is a sample data actually

Comment: How exactly you would like this string of comma separated property value pairs to be structured as an object?

Comment: Is there sth wrong?

Comment: how should I store geodata?

Comment: https://github.com/caseycesari/GeoJSON.js   I took the data from here

Answer (score 0):

According to the mapping at the given github link I guess you may do as i show below for the given case however for a general approach it is obviously better if you use that [github geoJSON library](https://github.com/caseycesari/GeoJSON.js) or if you are adventurous you may try to extend the following code...

```js
var dataStr = "name: 'Location A', category: 'Store', street: 'Market', lat: 39.984, lng: -75.343, name: 'Location B', category: 'House', street: 'Broad', lat: 39.284, lng: -75.833, name: 'Location C', category: 'Office', street: 'South', lat: 39.123, lng: -74.534",
    data    = dataStr.split(/\s*,\s*(?=name)/g)
                     .map(function(d){
                            return d.split(/\s*,\s*/)
                                    .reduce(function(r,s){
                                              var [k,v] = s.replace(/\s*'|'\s*$/g,"")
                                                           .split(":");
                                              return k === "name"    || 
                                                     k === "category" ? (r.properties[k] = v, r)
                                                                      : k === "lat" ||
                                                                        k === "lng"  ? (r.geometry.coordinates.unshift(+v), r)
                                                                                     : r;
                                            }, {type      : "feature",
                                                geometry  : {type : "Point", coordinates: [] },
                                                properties: {name    : "",
                                                             category: ""
                                                            }
                                               });
                                    }),
  geoJSON   = { type    : "FeatureCollection",
                features: data
              };

console.log(geoJSON);
```